# How to print an element contained in an array of state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        article: [],
        descArt: []
    };
}
```

`article` goes to populate after making a call with `axios` the result is:

[click to see console.log(this.state.article)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to4OR.png)

Then, I try to print an element in `render()` without success:

```
 render(){
    return(
        <Form>
            <Row>
                <FormGroup className="col-md-12">
                    <Label for="exampleEmail" md={3}>ADR</Label>
                    <Col md={6}>
                        <p>{this.state.article[0].ADR}</p>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
            </Row>
```

`this.setstate.article.ADR` or `this.state.article[0].ADR` (in both cases, `ADR` is undefined.

Why? on console.log it works!

The component for call:

[Getdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK9bE.png)

This is the call's success:

```
componentDidMount(){
    const stato = { service: "ArticoliCerca", article: this.props.article};
    getData(this, stato);

successCallback(service, response) {
    switch(service){
        case 'ArticoliCerca':
            this.setState({
                article: response.data.dati,
            });
            break;
```

Comment: please share complete code of this component

Comment: Please update this in your question

Comment: a quick hint is that you are reading from props instead of state, and the var name is different from the one in state, you are putting aritcolo instead of article...

Comment: Fixed, sorry, but i use the same code for other things

Comment: have you tried to safely render it `{this.state.article.length > 0?this.state.article[0].ADR:''}`

Comment: Tried now, length is undefined..

Comment: make sure you are setting the state correctly from your axios call, are you setting the correct response in the array ? please share your setState code, and the response of the axios call sample..

Comment: if the length is undefined it's more likely that `dati` is an object rather than an array

Comment: can you share the complete component code, it is hard to tell what's tell exactly what you're doing wrong withoug a more complete picture of what's going on

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show us where your logs are when they worked and what you're logging?

Comment: keys= object.keys(this.state.article), return 0
keys.length return 1